# Jumping between bookmarked ipython notebook cells in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscodevim

In large ipython notebooks (.ipynb files), it is tedious to constantly scroll up and down among cells that are far away in a notebook. In regular text files (like .py files), one can 'bookmark'  lines of code using markers (via vim keybindings). However markers don't let you jump between .ipynb cells. Is there another way to quickly jump between cells?

Typical vim keybindings for placing markers only work within a cell, but not for jumping between cells. Organizing a notebook with markdown headings and code folding make navigation faster, but the process is still very slow compared to using vim markers. Jump up one cell at a time works, but it can then require dozens of keystrokes to find the target cell. I also came across a 'table of contents' plugin for VSCode + Jupyter notebooks, but a) commenters say it doesn't work anymore b) this requires using the mouse for navigation, not keyboard.

Comment: Yes. It mostly lets you use vim to navigate within a cell, but not for jumping between cells, as far as I can tell.